Android Studio suddenly says no scripting plugin is loaded
My Kotlin app was running fine until a few days ago.
Then, I started doing a couple of changes (to the business logic of the app, no fundamental changes to the build configuration or anything).
Now that the codebase should be comipleable again, Android Studio 2024.1.2 (Koala) has unexpectedly started to tell me:

warning: default scripting plugin is disabled: The provided plugin org.jetbrains.kotlin.scripting.compiler.plugin.ScriptingCompilerConfigurationComponentRegistrar is not compatible with this version of compiler
error: unable to evaluate script, no scripting plugin loaded
Process finished with exit code 1

What does this mean and how can I fix it?
I have not touched any ScriptingCompilerConfigurationComponentRegistrar plugin and cannot find any information about it in the settings.

UPDATE: Upgrading Android Studio to 2024.2.1 (Ladybug) has not changed anything, the error still occurs.

I have no idea how this error emerged out of nowhere, but another answer helped me fix this issue:
Specificially, the suggestion to open my \.idea\workspace.xml file and remove the selected attribute from
<component name="RunManager" selected="Android App.app">

followed by cleaning and rebuilding the project made the error go away.
